# Aggregating results in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables (simplified) in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE party(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    family_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE election(
    id int,
    country_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    e_type election_type NOT NULL,
    e_date date NOT NULL,
    vote_share numeric,
    seats int,
    seats_total int NOT NULL,
    party_name_short varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    party_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_name_english varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_id int REFERENCES party(id)
);
```

I like to know how a certain political party family (Conservatives, Social Democracy and so on) in elections. To do so I wrote a simple query:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share
FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date,
    e.vote_share;
```

It almost does what I want. Please let me show you the results:

```
|country_name|year |vote_share|
|------------|-----|----------|
|Austria     |1983|1.4       |
|Austria     |1983|2         |
|Austria     |1986|4.8       |
|Austria     |1990|2         |
|Austria     |1990|4.8       |
```

As you can see instead of showing sum of vote share, the query shows vote share for every party. For 1983 there are two results: 1,4 and 2 because there were two parties in that election. What I want to sum of vote share. How do I do that?

Expected result:

```
|country_name|year |vote_share|
|------------|-----|----------|
|Austria     |1983|1.4 + 2    |
|Austria     |1986|4.8        |
|Austria     |1990|2 + 4,8    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the query below:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share
FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date,
    e.vote_share;
```

You sum on vote_share, great, but don't group by on vote_share.

This will do it:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share
FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date
```